# Problemas al mostrar imagen en el brandLabel del NavBar en Yii2

Tags: yii2, rutas

Pues algo raro me sucede al querer mostrar imagenes en el NavBar del menu principal, que se encuentra en la carpeta layout de las vistas

Inicialmente estaba usando la plantilla basica de Yii2, pero despues me doy cuenta que necesitaba usar frontend y backend, y hago el cambio para la plantilla avanzada.

Para la barra de menu de la aplicacion, uso un NavBar, en la que pongo una imagen en la propiedad 'brandLabel'.
En la plantilla basica todo funciona bien, pero en la avanzada no me muestra la imagen en la raiz del sitio (el index de la pagina de inicio), pero si la muestra en todas las demas paginas de la aplicacion.

Al parecer es algun problemas con la ruta, pero no entiendo lo que pasa

Lo que hice fue pasar todo lo que tenia en la plantilla basica para el frontend, y en common puse las configuraciones (conexion a la BD) que voy a necesitar tambien en el backend

La ruta de la imagen la puse asi: "../../web/img/sisleg60.png"

Si cambio la ruta y la pongo asi: "img/sisleg60.png"

entonces me sucede a la inversa, solo se ve la imagen en el index, y no en las demas paginas

Como puedo solucionar este problema?
Que estoy haciendo mal?

Nota: Nunca habia trabajado con la plantilla avanzada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero esto te ayude, 
Estoy obteniendo la Url con Yii::$app->getUrlManager() y le asigno la ruta base con getBaseUrl(), esta última llega hasta el directorio "web", teniendo en cuenta que dentro de web se encuentran tus carpetas "img(/img/logo.png")", "css", "js", estoy ocupando la plantilla advanced, se hace exactamente lo mismo en el frontend.

```
 <img class="navbar-brand"  src="<?= Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl()?>/img/logo.png">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu rapida respuesta. Pues con eso se soluciono el problema, ya me muestra la imagen desde cualquier pagina. El problema era que no sabia como llegar a la carpeta web.